# Spring Boot considers URL mapping as Thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I added this url mapping in my controller

```
@PostMapping("/print/purchase")
public void nameOfFunction(Request Body here) {
   // Some Code here
}
```

When I access this url I get this error `Exception processing template "mobile/app/daily/report/print/purchase": Er
ror resolving template [mobile/app/daily/report/print/purchase], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

Another things is that I added a `System.out.println("HERE!!!!!)` inside the function. Even though I get that error. The `HERE!!!!` is still printed in the console.

Why is Spring Boot considering the URL Mapping as a Thymeleaf Template?

Comment: What is your question? Anyway, the exception says that anywhere in you code you defined a template `"mobile/app/daily/report/print/purchase"`

Comment: @Patrick My code only contains this line `System.out.println("HERE!!!!!)` so I couldn't defined a template.

Comment: @Patrick the answer in your 2nd comment worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I see you are missing the closing quotation
just add " to the end of your request mapping as the follow

```
@PostMapping("/print/purchase")
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo